# Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift

Обучаюсь Swift и написал легкое приложения для Парсинга погоды. Оно представляет собой Tab Bar с двумя ViewController'ами. Погода в одном и второй это TableView. С помощью кнопки хочу сохранить определенные элементы в TableView, но натыкаюсь на "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"
Подскажите пожалуйста в каком моменте ошибка могла произойти?

Это ViewController, где отображается информация и находится кнопка делегат

Ошибку получаю при вызове делегата

`delegate.saveWeather(weather)`

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate {
    func saveWeather(_ weather: saveWeatherStruct)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var placeLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var humidityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var pressureLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var temperatureLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var feelsTemperatureLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var indicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var plusButton: UIButton!
    
    
    let apiManager = ApiManager()
    var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       getWeather()
    }
    
    @IBAction func plusButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        save()
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonAction() {
        indicator(on: true)
        getWeather()
    }
    private func save() {
        guard let weatherName = placeLable.text else { return }
        guard let temperature = temperatureLable.text else { return }
        print(weatherName)
        print(temperature)
        
        let weather = saveWeatherStruct(place: weatherName, temperature: temperature)
        delegate.saveWeather(weather)
    }
    
    func getWeather() {
        apiManager.getWeather { data, error in
            if let _ = error {
                self.failedAlert(message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            }
            self.indicator(on: false)
            self.isHidden(on: false)
            self.placeLable.text = data?.name
            self.humidityLabel.text = data?.main.humidityString
            self.pressureLable.text = data?.main.pressureString
            self.temperatureLable.text = data?.main.temperatureString
            self.feelsTemperatureLable.text = data?.main.appearentTemperatureString
        }
    }
    
    private func failedAlert(message: String) {
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Failed",
                                    message: message,
                                    preferredStyle: .alert)
      let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { [weak self] _ in
        self?.getWeather()
      }
      alert.addAction(okAction)
      present(alert, animated: true)
    }
```

TableView

```
class WeatherCloud: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var weatherList: [saveWeatherStruct] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let addWeatherVC = segue.destination as! ViewController
        addWeatherVC.delegate = self
    }
}

extension WeatherCloud: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        weatherList.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Weather", for: indexPath)
        let weather = weatherList[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(weather.place) \(weather.temperature)"
        return cell
    }
}
extension WeatherCloud: ViewControllerDelegate {
    func saveWeather(_ weather: saveWeatherStruct) {
        weatherList.append(weather)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
weak var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate!
```

Comment: Вот такая ошибка получилась теперь 
`'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'ViewControllerDelegate'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound `

Comment: protocol ViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject

Comment: Добавил и это, но все равно delegate равняется nil. Уже перепробовал переподключение всех аутлетов, но ничего не помогло.
Информация есть, которая доходит до делегата, но сам делегат равняется nil

Comment: Если хотите, выложите проект на гитхаб или пришлите мне в почту, посмотрю код.

Comment: Отправил на почту, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Посмотрел, ответил.

Answer (score 0):

безопасная проверка на нил:

```
if let weather = saveWeatherStruct(place: weatherName, temperature: temperature),
   let delegate = delegate
{
    delegate.saveWeather(weather)
}
```

читать следует так:

- если удается присвоить значение weather которое является значимым (не нилом)
- если делегат является не нилом

то delegate.saveWeather.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if let vcs = tabBarController?.viewControllers, vcs.count > 1, let vc = vcs[1] as? WeatherCloud {
        _ = vc.view 
        delegate = vc
    }
```

Решение, спасибо Олегу Соловьеву
Это необходимо было добавить во ViewController потому что не срабатывала func.prepare()